# Not able to Read serial data from Arduino and wireless modem due serial port opening case

Tags: python, python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial

I have posted some complex question earlier similar to this but in much simpler way.
The major issue is whenever I am selecting the port from the drop-down menu and trying to open it to read the data from Arduino or wireless modem.

Every time I have to face the error of serial port not open.

The hard-code in which I am fixing the COM port is working perfectly fine

Mentioned below is the code I have simplified and trying to work with

```
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
from tkinter import *

ard = serial.Serial();
ard.baudrate = 9600

master = Tk()

variable = StringVar(master)

a=serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
for w in a: 
    print(w.device)
dev = [w.device]
print(dev)
variable.set(dev[0]) # default value
w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *dev)
w.pack()
ard.port = str(w)
ard.open
ard.is_open
#print(k)

def ok():
    print (variable.get())
    k = ard.readline()

button = Button(master, text="OK", command=ok)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

but every time I am facing the error

```
COM4
['COM4']
COM4
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Misha\Desktop\test\autoserial.py", line 27, in ok
    k = ard.readline()
  File "C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 267, in read
    raise portNotOpenError
serial.serialutil.SerialException: Attempting to use a port that is not open
```

Please suggest which help me to make this work, Your leads will be a great help for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `ard.open` in your code, but you aren't actually calling the method to open your serial connection. This is why you are getting an error saying `Attempting to use a port that is not open`. Try `ard.open()` to see if this works. This should open your port and make it usable.

However, given your setup, you probably want to wrap this around a callback that you can tie to another button or the `OptionMenu`. It seems you'll want to the flexibility to choose ports and only open the port after choosing one.

Here's a small example of what it might look like:

```
import tkinter as tk
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports

ard = serial.Serial();
ard.baudrate = 9600

a = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
ports = [port.device for port in a]

def open_serial():
    ard.port = variable.get()
    ard.open()
    print(f'Port {variable.get()} opened')

def close_serial():
    p = ard.port
    ard.close()
    print(f'Port {p} closed')

master = tk.Tk()
variable = tk.StringVar()
variable.set(ports[0])
options = tk.OptionMenu(master, variable, *ports)
options.pack()
button_open = tk.Button(master, text='Open', command=open_serial)
button_open.pack()
button_close = tk.Button(master, text='Close', command=close_serial)
button_close.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: After using ard.port() Error is : 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Misha\Desktop\test\autoserial.py", line 21, in <module>
    ard.open()
  File "C:\Users\Misha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\serial\serialwin32.py", line 62, in open
    raise SerialException("could not open port {!r}: {!r}".format(self.portstr, ctypes.WinError()))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port '.!optionmenu': FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)

Comment: And yes I want to choose the port and open the port after choosing anyone.

Comment: I think you should try what I suggested in the second paragraph rather than just throwing parentheses after `ard.open`. You want to be able to control when you open the ports, specifically after you've chosen which port you want to open. I think adding another button that will open the port is a good route for this.

Comment: actually, I am new with python and I am working on the desktop application. Can you give me some sample which helps me to modify my code accordingly?

Comment: Great! Since this was helpful, please consider [accepting and/or upvoting this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).